# multiple CanvasJS with multiple JSon files

Tags: html, json, canvasjs

Im very new to html coding,
Im trying to display multiple charts using different json files, in this code the second chart will not render.
What am i doing wrong?
Thank you for your patience and help.

https://pastebin.com/VNDp7RAr

My 11.json contents are :

`[["January",344957],["feb",24957]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method to read json file & passing it to chart as shown in [this tutorial](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/render-multiple-charts-in-a-page/) should work fine in this case.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.npoint.io/1cac2e661da6c95f5778", function(data) {            
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      dps1.push({x: value[0], y: parseInt(value[1])});
    }); 
  });
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xyjud9a/12/) for a working sample.